# subversion client search engine gui

Tags: svn, user-interface, client

I am looking for a SVN Search Engine GUI on top of subversion
subversion current size is 1.5 TerraBytes of data

My requirements are

1. initial scan should be multithreaded
2. post commit trigger to index new commits
3. Indexing server and search  operations should be separated.(not mandatory)
4. Viewer access to source via links back to SVN or must have AD Id/and Group based Auth

I found fish eye would suite the requirement. Suggest me if any other tool meet the requirements.